# Combining Masonry with other jQuery effects

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I'm using the Masonry plugin to float elements on a page, and it uses the class `.item` to apply the Masonry effect to divs.

I'd like to apply `.fadeOut` and `.fadeIn` to multiple divs that are already Masonry `.items`, but since I can't apply the same id to different divs, this is proving to be difficult.

Here's what I'm doing now, which is not working properly:

JS:

```
$("#shapiro").click(function() {
      $('#container div:not(#id1)').fadeOut('fast');
      $('#id1').fadeIn('fast');
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item" class="id1">some content</div>
    <div class="item" class="id1">some content</div>
    <div class="item" class="id2">some content</div>
    <div class="item" class="id2">some content</div>
</div>
```

I've tried applying multiple classes to each div, but that's not working either.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I can see here is that having multiple `class=""` statements might confuse browsers. You can add multiple classes by space-separating them:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item id1">some content</div>
    <div class="item id1">some content</div>
    <div class="item id2">some content</div>
    <div class="item id2">some content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't IDs be used only if they are unique? Otherwise use a class.

Comment: it's always the little things. @JamWaffles Thanks, didnt know about that

Comment: Glad I could be of service :-)